# Question about If Else statments and changing a variable

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a question about a google app script I'm working on. I am completely new to this. I would like to be able to have a script run on a button press and duplicate the current sheet. I would then like it to be renamed based on the name of the active sheet. When I return the value of newName with a browser.msgBox the value of newName is defined. However when I test the script the error reads "Cannot read property 'setName' of null". Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

````
var name = ss.getSheetName();
var newName = ""


function newMonth() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();  

  if (name == "January") {
  newName = "February";
} else if (name == "February") {
  newName = "March";
} else if (name == "March") {
  newName = "April";
} else if (name == "April") {
  newName = "May";
} else if (name == "May") {
  newName = "June";
} else if (name == "June") {
  newName = "July";
} else if (name == "July") {
  newName = "August";
} else if (name == "August") {
  newName = "September";
} else if (name == "September") {
  newName = "October";
} else if (name == "October") {
  newName = "November";
} else if (name == "November") {
  newName = "December";    
} else {
  Browser.msgBox("Please Create New Sheet")
}

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Copy of ${name}").setName(newName);

};```
````

Comment: In your showing script, when you run the function of `newMonth()`, I think that an error occurs at `var name = ss.getSheetName();`. Because `ss` is not declared. So I cannot understand `However when I test the script the error reads "Cannot read property 'setName' of null".`. And, I'm worried that you have miscopied your current script. How about this?

Comment: Oh yes I did not copy the function correctly. I left out the declaration of ss. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tanaike that ss is not declared when running the function, I get the error after correcting that, this is the change that you can use to fix the error `"Cannot read property 'setName' of null"`:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(`Copy of ${name}`).setName(newName);
```

To embed variables into a String you need to use bactick(`) charactes. Also, you might get an error if you don't enter a name and leave newName as "", this is the code that I used to solve the errors:

```
var newName = ""


function newMonth() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = ss.getSheetName();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();  

  if (name == "January") {
  newName = "February";
} else if (name == "February") {
  newName = "March";
} else if (name == "March") {
  newName = "April";
} else if (name == "April") {
  newName = "May";
} else if (name == "May") {
  newName = "June";
} else if (name == "June") {
  newName = "July";
} else if (name == "July") {
  newName = "August";
} else if (name == "August") {
  newName = "September";
} else if (name == "September") {
  newName = "October";
} else if (name == "October") {
  newName = "November";
} else if (name == "November") {
  newName = "December";    
} else {
  Browser.msgBox("Please Create New Sheet");
}

if(newName != "") SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(`Copy of ${name}`).setName(newName);

};
```

Reference:

- [Template Strings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the function for me. I had no idea about the backticks,I think I misread them in the documentation as quotations. And thanks for adding the if statement at the end.